# override equals method in User class

Tags: java, equals

I am working on existing project. I have below user class's equals method. when I compare equality with equals I get false on

```
if (getClass() != other.getClass()) {
  return false;
}
```

The coomplete `equals` code:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
  if (this == obj) {
    return true;
  }

  if (obj == null) {
    return false;
  }

  User other = (User) obj;
  if (getClass() != other.getClass()) {
    return false;
  }

  if (this.getUserId() == null) {
    if (other.getUserId() != null) {
      return false;
    }
  } else if (!this.getUserId().equals(other.getUserId())) {
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

Do I require to check the class type here? If yes, why are my user classes are different? Why can not I put to check class type like below?

```
if (!(obj instanceof User)){
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I found, User class from hibernate layer/DAO is not a direct User class. It's sub class of User or a proxy. So, When I check with obj.getClass() it gives false.

In such cases, better not comparing with getClass().

I checked with instanceof.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (getClass() != other.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
```

This check should be placed before the casting:

```
User other = (User) obj;
```

---

The difference between `instanceof` and `getClass()` is that the latter ensures that the type is not a sub-type. So:

```
User user = new SubUser();
boolean a = user instanceof User;
boolean b = user.getClass() == User.class;
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(b);
```

would print:

```
true
false
```

Comment: agreed, but why my code returns false on getClass(), if i pass user object? here, currentUser.equals(query.getQueryLockBy())

Comment: @CHowdappaM It seems that the object type of `currentUser` is different from the object type of `query.getQueryLockBy()`.

Comment: Thanks. But i am 101% sure both are User. I have only one user class. Btw, currentUser taken from session. query's user is just detached object from hibernate session. Is this making difference?

Comment: @CHowdappaM I am not experienced with Hibernate, but it could generate sub type of User by itself (You can test the class name by using, `obj.getClass().getName()`). If so, you could use `instanceof` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `instanceOf` method to avoid a `ClassCastException` later. This Exception will be thrown if you use the equals method with the wrong object type.

Answer (score 0):

The [Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683) book by Joshua Bloch provides very good suggestions to implement many, what one might consider, standard situations. It includes an approach to implementing the `equals` method.

Here is a modified implementation:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
  if (this == obj) {
    return true;
  }

  if (!(obj instanceof User)) { // this covers the null check
    return false;
  }

  User other = (User) obj; // this is now safe

  if ((this.getUserId() == null) && other.getUserId() != null) {
      return false
  } else if ((this.getUserId() != null) && !this.getUserId().equals(other.getUserId())) {
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

It is not so obvious, but the `instanceof` check returns `false` for `null` values simply because there is no way identify their type (i.e. nulls are untyped).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think you should inverse the lines

```
        User other = (User) obj;
        if (getClass() != other.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
```

to become

```
    if (getClass() != other.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    User other = (User) obj;
```

Secondly, the equals method is an important one in the java collections library and in a lot of others as well so you should really think about any implementation details.

Suppose you have an Employee class (with an id) being subclassed into Manager, so you might consider writing an equals method on Employee just checking the id and you are fine. But, are you ? It depends.

So if you check in employee equals method it will return true if you pass a manager. But if you check on class equality by using getClass, it will return false when you pass a manager.

Suppose these 2 classes are stored in a database into an employee table and into a manager table respectively, the database has the id as a column which is defined as as an autoincrement column. Which means you can have an employee with id 100 who is a totally different person than a manager with id 100.

On the other hand you can have a single employee table storing all employees and managers. Hence here if you have an employee object with id 100 and a manager with id 100 then they must be the same person.

Comment: My original code as same as you mentioned. I was playing with instanceof and placed here and there. I don't have sub classes to User.

Comment: While there are some cases where it may make sense to have objects of different types compare equal, I would not consider your example a particularly good one.  The type of a thing which represents a person should not change when the person gets promoted.  Instead, one should have encapsulate within an object which is of the same type for everyone one or more inheritable-class objects (perhaps derived from e.g. `EmployeeDuties` and/or `EmployeeEarnings`).  That would allow the `Employee` object representing a line worker to continue to represent that person after his promotion.

Answer (score 0):

For your question, you should put

```
 getClass() != other.getClass()
```

before

```
 User other = (User) obj;
```

Equqality is an interesting question. And many people discussed about it. One detail dicussion on equality can be seen in *Programming in Scala* 2nd Chapter30.

Answer (score -1):

here you stated that you don't have any subclasses of User so you can use instanceof check.

Comment: maybe you should, maybe not, it depends on what business wise your equals method should do !